# Problema subiendo archivo TXT firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio

bueno les cuento que estoy intentando generar un bucle que respalde archivos txt, el tema es que cuando lo lanzo me tira muchos errores y en teoría sale que ya se subieron todos los archivos pero ninguno se subio :C

```java
public Void then(final Task<Route> task) throws Exception {
                        int n = 1;


                        while (true){
                            File f = new File("/data/data/com.example.me/files",String.valueOf(n)+".txt");


                            if (f.exists()){
                                Log.i("eule","Ya existe elemento"+ n);
                                Log.i("eule","Se subira el archivo");
                                Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("/data/data/com.example.me/files",String.valueOf(n)+".txt"));
                                mStorageRef.putFile(file);
                                n++;
                            }
```

```java
E/StorageException: Cannot upload to getRoot. You should upload to a storage location such as .getReference('image.png').putFile...
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot upload to getRoot. You should upload to a storage location such as .getReference('image.png').putFile...
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.0:205)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.0:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

EDIT:
Link de firebase:gs://mmripre.appspot.com 
Lo unico de referencia que tengo es esto(es lo unico que salia en el tutorial):

```java
mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
```

Comment: Publica el código donde obtienes la referencia a `mStorageRef`. Ahí va a estar el problema. Le tienes que indicar una ruta. Si hiciste algo como esto: `FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()` no te va a funcionar porque le tienes que indicar en getReference la ruta donde lo quieres subir. Sino asume que al root y ahí no te deja por lo que puedes ver.

Comment: @SuperG280 Agregado, no entendí a lo que te referías.... me lo puedes explicar...